# If $p^2=a^2(\cos x)^2+b^2(\sin x)^2$, prove that $p +\frac{d^2 p}{dx^2}=\frac{a^2 b^2}{p^3}$

Tags: derivatives

How to prove this? It seems simple enough to start but the at the end I cannot prove the expression $p +\frac{d^2 p}{dx^2}=\frac{a^2 b^2}{p^3}$. Is there a particular trick I am missing or is this just an ordinary sum with lots of manipulation. I did try modifying the question slightly by multiplying both the LHS and RHS by $p^3$. That seems to lessen the manipulation somewhat but still the answer does not come.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. It would be great if you edit your post and write where you got stuck. An isolated problem (without any context or work) might attract downvotes and closevotes.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 There has been a response, thanks for the comment. The question is definitely better now.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: This is the first time such comment affected an answer in the positive. This is indeed a not-so-common case, you know!

Comment: And for this, @Afnan take my upvote!! :) Cheers for the first reputation!

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Won't be the last time for sure, thanks so much anyway. Afnan, take my up vote as well!

Comment: This question is nice, actually. The internet is posting those same answers. I will look for an elegant proof (it may take time), and put it if I get one.

Answer (score 0):

$$p^2 = a^2 \cos^2 x + b^2(1 -\cos ^2 x) = (a^2-b^2)\cos^2x +b^2 = (a^2-b^2)\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\cos 2x}{2} \right) +b^2 \\= \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} + \frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos 2x}{2}$$
So differentiating, we get
$$2pp' = -(a^2-b^2)\sin 2x \tag{1}$$
$$2(p')^2 + 2pp'' = -2(a^2-b^2)\cos 2x \tag{2} $$
Adding $(2) \times p^2$ and  $-\frac{1}{2}(1)^2$, we get
$$-2(pp')^2 + 2(pp')^2 + 2p^3p'' =- \frac{(a^2-b^2)^2\sin^2 2x}{2}   -2(a^2-b^2)\cos 2x \cdot p^2$$
Now adding $2p^4$ to both sides,
\begin{align}
2p^4 + 2p^3p'' &= -\frac{(a^2-b^2)^2\sin^2 2x}{2}   -2p^2[(a^2-b^2)\cos 2x \cdot- p^2] \\
&= -\frac{(a^2-b^2)^2\sin^2 2x}{2} -2p^2\left( \frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos 2x}{2} - \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \right)\\
&=- \frac{(a^2-b^2)^2\sin^2 2x}{2}\\ 
&\ \ -2 \left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2} + \frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos 2x}{2} \right) \left( \frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos 2x}{2} - \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \right)\\
&=- \frac{(a^2-b^2)^2\sin^2 2x}{2} - 2\left( \left(\frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos 2x}{2} \right)^2-\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{4}    \right)\\
&= \frac{-(a^2-b^2)^2\sin^2 2x -(a^2-b^2)^2\cos^2 2x + (a^2 +b^2)^2 }{2}\\
&==\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2 - (a^2-b^2)^2}{2} = 2a^2b^2 
\end{align}
That is,
$$p^4 + p^3p'' = a^2b^2 $$